# Compare two delimited files field by field and find the missing and non matching records

Tags: shell, awk

Two input files each having 3 fields. The first two fields in both the files have to matched and the third field has to be compared.

```
    File1
A ; 1 ; a1
B ; 2 ; b2
C ; 3 ; c3
A ; 4 ; a4


 File 2
B ; 2 ; b2
C ; 3 ; c5
E ; 5 ; e5
```

I want output like below.

```
Mismatching: 
C ; 3 ; c3

Lines missing in file1:
E ; 5 ; e5

Lines missing in file2: 
A ; 1 ; a1
A ; 4 ; a4
```

I also want the records missing in file1 and file2.

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ";"} NR==FNR{a[$1,$2] = $3; next} (a[$1,$2] != $3)' file1 file2
```

but this is giving me only the rows in file2 which are not present in file1..

Comment: You're in luck, the archives are chock full of examples of how to do this. Just search them.

Comment: I tried awk 'BEGIN {FS = ";"} NR==FNR{a $1,$2} = $3; next} (a[$1,$2] != $3)' file1 file2.. but this is giving me only the rows in file2 which are not present in file1..

Comment: Why don't you call the script again with file1 and file2 swapped? (to get the rows in file1 which are not present in file2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F';' '
   NR==FNR{a[$1","$2]=$0; next}

   $1","$2 in a{if(a[$1","$2] != $0)mm=mm $0 RS; delete a[$1","$2]; next}
   {nf=nf $0 RS}

   END{print "Mismatching:\n" mm;
       print "Lines missing in file1:"; for(i in a)print a[i];
       print "\nLines missing in file2:\n" nf}
   ' file2 file1
Mismatching:
C ; 3 ; c3

Lines missing in file1:
E ; 5 ; e5

Lines missing in file2:
A ; 1 ; a1
A ; 4 ; a4
```

- `$1","$2 in a` if first two fields are found in `a`

  - if value in `a` doesn't match current line, append the line to variable `mm` (mismatch lines)
  - delete the key from `a` so that at the end whichever keys were not called upon will give missing lines
- `nf=nf $0 RS` if the key wasn't found in `a` then we get lines not found in first file argument passed to `awk`
- `END{...}` print as required

Better to save code in a file and call it using `-f`

```
$ cat cmp.awk 
NR==FNR{a[$1","$2]=$0; next}

$1","$2 in a{if(a[$1","$2] != $0)mm=mm $0 RS; delete a[$1","$2]; next}
{nf=nf $0 RS}

END{print "Mismatching:\n" mm;
    print "Lines missing in file1:"; for(i in a)print a[i];
    print "\nLines missing in file2:\n" nf}

$ awk -F';' -f cmp.awk file2 file1
```